# генерация трансляции на youtube c++

Tags: c++, youtube, youtube-api

Возник такой вопрос. У меня есть некоторое количество камер, они шлют в мою серверную софтину видеопотоки, там я провожу некоторую обработку и формирую итоговый видеопоток, который рассылается далее клиентам. Появилась необходимость дополнительно слать этот поток в трансляцию на youtube. Изначально генерировал свой поток на оверлей, захватывал его XSplit-om или OBS-ом и так гнал на Youtube, но хочется делать это напрямую из своего софта. Возможно ли это? Насколько я смог понять из гугления - API под с++ для youtube - нет. Возможно есть иные варианты?
платформа - win10, компилятор - msvc

Comment: «api для youtube» называется протокол rtmp, и можно просто взять любую библиотеку для работы с rtmp, хоть тот же ffmpeg например

Comment: API под С++? Что?)

Comment: API у них под http